# How to work with web server on embedded linux

Tags: webserver, embedded-linux

I am not experienced in development for embedded Linux so I will be glad if the answers are as detailed as possible.

I have a board with an ARM chip and Linux. I need to make a Web GUI for an application that runs on Linux.
I installed and started the thttpd server, but I do not understand well how to make the connection between the web server and the C application.

For example, in the C application there is work with uart, I need to transfer data from web forms to uart and update the data arriving from uart on web page.

Comment: Are you constrained to use C?  Is python an option?

Comment: i know only C\C++, and learning python is not an option.

Comment: Learning Python (to the level of something easy) is 1 evening. Seriously, it has one of the lowest threshold of entrance. With it in the pocket you may do much better and faster development.